# Why the Share Tray Labeled Intent LinkedIn Icon not displayed while sharing content in Android 10 OS

Tags: java, android, share, linkedin-api

I am sharing plain/text via Intent share using Share tray read the package name from and filter the App in labeled intent. Some application is showing in that list and have Linkedin package name also in that list but not showing the Linkedin icon in share tray. Why that icon not displayed?

Device: Samsung Galaxy S10
OS: Android Version 10
[image: Galaxy S10 sharetray]

**Code which I Tried**

```
 PackageManager pm=getActivityContext.getPackageManager();
        Intent sendIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

        Intent receiver=new Intent(getActivityContext, UserSelectedShareBroadcast.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivityContext, 0, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Intent openInChooser=Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Choose", pendingIntent.getIntentSender());
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo=pm.queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0);
        List<LabeledIntent> intentList=new ArrayList<>();

        Intent externalEmailIntent=new Intent(getActivityContext, ExternalEmailShareActivity.class);
        externalEmailIntent.putExtra("programId", programId);
        intentList.add(new LabeledIntent(externalEmailIntent, "packagename", "Email to", R.drawable.ic_mail_outline));

        for (int i=0; i < resInfo.size(); i++) {
            // Extract the label, append it, and repackage it in a LabeledIntent
            ResolveInfo ri=resInfo.get(i);
            String packageName=ri.activityInfo.packageName;
            //Enabled Tweet sharing
            /*if (packageName.contains("twitter")) {
                emailIntent.setPackage(packageName);
            } else*/
            if (packageName.contains("twitter") || packageName.contains("facebook") ||
                    packageName.contains("whatsapp") || packageName.contains("linkedin") ||
                    packageName.contains("com.google.android.apps.docs") ||
                    packageName.contains("com.google.android.gm") ||
                    packageName.contains("com.Slack")) {
                Intent intent=new Intent();
                try {
                    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, ri.activityInfo.name));
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setType("text/plain");
                    //intent.setType("text/plain/image");
                    if (packageName.contains("twitter")) {
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sharedURL);
                    } else if (packageName.contains("facebook")) {
                        // Warning: Facebook IGNORES our text. They say "These fields are intended for users to express themselves. Pre-filling these fields erodes the authenticity of the user voice."
                        // One workaround is to use the Facebook SDK to post, but that doesn't allow the user to choose how they want to share. We can also make a custom landing page, and the link
                        // will show the <meta content ="..."> text from that page with our link in Facebook.
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sharedURL);
                    } else if (packageName.contains("whatsapp")) {
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sharedURL);
                    } else if (packageName.contains("linkedin")) {
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sharedURL);
                    } else if (packageName.contains("com.google.android.apps.docs")) {
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sharedURL);
                    } else if (packageName.contains("com.Slack")) {
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sharedURL);
                    }else if (packageName.contains("android.gm")) {
                    // If Gmail shows up twice, try removing this else-if clause and the reference to "android.gm" above
                    //intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(resources.getString(R.string.share_email_gmail)));
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, str_title);
                    intent.setType("message/rfc822");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sharedURL);
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(publicThumbnail);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                }

                    intentList.add(new LabeledIntent(intent, packageName, ri.loadLabel(pm), ri.icon));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                  intent=null;
                }
            }
        }

        // convert intentList to array

        LabeledIntent[] extraIntents=intentList.toArray(new LabeledIntent[intentList.size()]);

        openInChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, extraIntents);
        getActivityContext.startActivityForResult(openInChooser, REQUEST_SHARED_URL);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some changes in your code to make post on LinkedIn via Intent. Please check my code which is given below. I have tested in android 10 os and it is working fine. hope it helps.

```
 private void shareTray(){
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sharedURL);

    Intent receiver=new Intent(getActivityContext, UserSelectedShareBroadcast.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivityContext, 0, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    PackageManager pm=getActivityContext.getPackageManager();
    Intent openInChooser=Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Choose", pendingIntent.getIntentSender());
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo=pm.queryIntentActivities(sharingIntent, 0);
    List<LabeledIntent> intentList=new ArrayList<>();

    Intent externalEmailIntent=new Intent(getActivityContext, ExternalEmailShareActivity.class);
            externalEmailIntent.putExtra("INBOX", "Inbox");
    intentList.add(new LabeledIntent(externalEmailIntent, "yourpackagename", "Email to", R.drawable.ic_mail_outline));

    for (int i=0; i < resInfo.size(); i++) {
        ResolveInfo ri=resInfo.get(i);
        String packageName=ri.activityInfo.packageName;
        if (packageName.contains("twitter")) {
            sharingIntent.setPackage(packageName);
        } else{
            if (packageName.contains("twitter") || packageName.contains("facebook") ||
                    packageName.contains("whatsapp") || packageName.contains("linkedin") ||
                    packageName.contains("com.google.android.apps.docs") ||
                    packageName.contains("com.google.android.gm") ||
                    packageName.contains("com.Slack")) {
                Intent shareIntent=new Intent();
                try {
                    shareIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, ri.activityInfo.name));
                    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    //shareIntent.setType("text/plain/image");
                    if (packageName.contains("twitter")) {
                        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sharedURL);
                    } else if (packageName.contains("facebook")){shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sharedURL);
                    } else if (packageName.contains("whatsapp")) {
                        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sharedURL);
                    } else if (packageName.contains("linkedin")) {
                        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, sharedURL);
                        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sharedURL);
                    } else if (packageName.contains("com.google.android.apps.docs")) {
                        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sharedURL);
                    } else if (packageName.contains("com.Slack")) {
                        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sharedURL);
                    }else if (packageName.contains("android.gm")) {
                        // If Gmail shows up twice, try removing this else-if clause and the reference to "android.gm" above
                        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, str_title);
                        shareIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sharedURL);
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(publicThumbnail);
                        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                    }

                    intentList.add(new LabeledIntent(shareIntent, packageName, ri.loadLabel(pm), ri.icon));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    shareIntent=null;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    // convert intentList to array
    LabeledIntent[] extraIntents=intentList.toArray(new LabeledIntent[intentList.size()]);

    openInChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, extraIntents);
    getActivityContext.startActivityForResult(openInChooser, REQUEST_SHARED_URL);

}
```

Happy Coding..